# Getting undesired output in SQL Server while using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am looking for an output of:

[image: Desired Output]

but getting this instead:

[image: result got]

The two tables which I have used are [`Table 1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9hkQ.png) and [`Table 2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPcPN.png).

I am providing the links for the table as well [Kaggle Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results)

The code I have

```
SELECT * 
FROM   
    (SELECT
         nr.region, Medal, 
         COUNT(Medal) AS 'Total_Medal' 
     FROM
         athlete_events AS ae
     JOIN
         noc_regions AS nr ON ae.NOC = nr.NOC
     WHERE
         Medal <> 'NA'
     GROUP BY 
         Medal, nr.region) AS t1
PIVOT 
    (COUNT(Medal) 
         FOR Medal IN ([Gold], [Silver], [Bronze])
    ) pivot_table
ORDER BY
    Total_Medal DESC
```

Please help me to solve this, consider me a novice

Comment: Why do you have `Group by Medal, nr.region` instead of `Group by nr.region`?

Comment: I believe if we won't use it will through an error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: apologies, I have added links for the table

Comment: can you add a table with a sample data?

Comment: Sorry, @Viki_29. I misread your query so my question was dumb.

Comment: You are pre-aggregating the data - and then counting (pivot) the number of rows for each aggregate.  So you end up with 1 Gold for USA and not a count of the number of golds.  Try removing the grouping in the inner query and the total medals count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably just want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT nr.region, medal
 FROM athlete_events ae INNER JOIN noc_regions nr
  ON ae.noc = nr.noc
 WHERE medal <> 'NA'
) t1
PIVOT(COUNT(medal) FOR medal in ([Gold], [Silver], [Bronze])) pt
ORDER BY gold+silver+bronze DESC
```

There doesn't appear to be any reason for your inner `group`ing and `count`ing. The `pivot` can handle the count and, since you don't want `total medal` in your output (except for the order), you can just sum the medal fields in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This, you will get exact output

```
Select OH.Region,
Count(Case When O.Medal='Gold' Then 1 End) AS Gold,
Count(Case When O.Medal='Silver' Then 1 End) AS Silver,
Count(Case When O.Medal='Bronze' Then 1 End) AS Bronze
from athlete_events O
Join noc_regions OH On OH.NOC = O.NOC 
Group by OH.Region
Order By Gold Desc,Silver Desc,Bronze Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

So I kinda gave up on pivot myself. Caused me to many problems in the past (always my own mistakes ofcourse) and when I can I try a different approache.

So I'll show you a query that tells you how you can get the results you want, but it won't answer your pivot question. This method isn't the most efficient, but it's fine for a size of these records and I think it makes the query even more readable.

```
SELECT 
    region
    , SUM(Gold) AS 'Gold'
    , SUM(Silver) AS 'Silver'
    , SUM(Bronze) AS 'Bronze'
FROM
    noc_regions
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT NOC, COUNT(*) AS 'Gold' FROM athlete_events WHERE Medal = 'Gold' GROUP BY NOC) gold_events ON noc_regions.NOC = gold_events.NOC
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT NOC, COUNT(*) AS 'Silver' FROM athlete_events WHERE Medal = 'Silver' GROUP BY NOC) silver_events ON noc_regions.NOC = silver_events.NOC             
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT NOC, COUNT(*) AS 'Bronze' FROM athlete_events WHERE Medal = 'Bronze' GROUP BY NOC) bronze_events ON noc_regions.NOC = bronze_events.NOC
GROUP BY
    region
ORDER BY
    Gold DESC
    , Silver DESC
    , Bronze DESC
    , region ASC;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much. i really appreciate your time to solve this